# Django validationError from jquery post.fail() into normal message (displays "[u'text here']")

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have created a validation error in my models.py that shows when people try to save an appointment in the past (my app is a kind of calendar). This all works. (btw: I use ugettext_laxy as _)

```
raise ValidationError(_('SomeText')
```

However, now I'm using ajax post calls to create new appointments. They give back the 400 BAD REQUEST response, which I capture in the .fail() block in the javascript and show in a popup:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            showPopupMessage(jqXHR.responseJSON.error, 'danger');
            });
```

So far so good. The popup and everything works.

However, the showed text inside the jqXHR.responseJSON.error object is like this:

```
"[u'SomeText']"
```

Which means that the text inside the popup shows like this:

```
[u'SomeText'].
```

ie, it looks like a unpacked python string inside a list. Is there a way to unpack this using javascript/jquery?

I've been working on this for several hours, for something that should be so easy for a javascript guru... (I'm new to javascript)... So thanks a lot!

EDIT: I'm using tastypie, so I guess I use those views?

Comment: Please show the view that returns the ajax response. If you're using Django 1.7, you might find the [`form.errors.as_json()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json) method helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm using Django tastypie, so I did not create views myself. Would you recommend creating views myself instead of using an api framework for this kind of stuff?